# RewardspointsFactory class does not exist

Tags: database, collection, class, factory

Please anyone review my code.
Facing this error.
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\RewardspointsFactory does not exist
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\RewardspointsFactory does not exist

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Model\Total;

class Fee extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal {

    /**
     * Collect grand total address amount
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
     * @return $this
     */
    protected $quoteValidator = null;

    protected $rewardspointCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteValidator $quoteValidator,
            \Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\RewardspointsFactory $rewardspointCollectionFactory
            ) {
        $this->quoteValidator = $quoteValidator;
        $this->rewardspointCollectionFactory = $rewardspointCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function collect(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    ) {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);


        $exist_amount = 0; //$quote->getFee(); 
        $fee = 200; //Excellence_Fee_Model_Fee::getFee();
        $balance = $fee - $exist_amount;

        $total->setTotalAmount('fee', $balance);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('fee', $balance);

        $total->setFee($balance);
        $total->setBaseFee($balance);

        $total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal() + $balance);
        $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal() + $balance);


        return $this;
    }

    protected function clearValues(Address\Total $total) {
        $total->setTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('tax', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('tax', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setSubtotalInclTax(0);
        $total->setBaseSubtotalInclTax(0);
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param Address\Total $total
     * @return array|null
     */

    /**
     * Assign subtotal amount and label to address object
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param Address\Total $total
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function fetch(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total) {


        $rewardspointCollection = $this->rewardspointCollectionFactory->create();
        $customerId = $quote->getCustomerId();
        $rewardspointCollection->addFieldToSelect('*')
                ->addFieldToFilter('dukaaniatest_id',$customerId);
        if(count($rewardspointCollection) > 0){
           $firstItem =  $rewardspointCollection->geFirstItem();
           return [
            'code' => 'fee',
            'title' => $firstItem->getData('title'),
            'value' => $firstItem->getData('author')
        ];
        }else{
            return [
            'code' => 'fee',
            'title' => 'Fee',
            'value' => 0
        ];
        }



    }

    /**
     * Get Subtotal label
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getLabel() {
        return __('Fee');
    }

}
```

Comment: Make sure you are calling the right file and your naming conversion is proper. As per magento standard there should be collection.php in the path you have mentioned i.e `Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\CollectionFactory`

Comment: /home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/ResourceModel/Fee/Collection.php

so the path i set is
 \Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Fee\CollectionFactory $rewardspointCollectionFactory

Comment: As per your comment you should change your injected class from `\Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\RewardspointsFactory` to `\Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Fee\CollectionFactory`

Comment: the code is run but it shows a blank page and just
Estimate Shipping and Tax written on that

Comment: Try clearing your generated and cache. If still not getting enable log or error reporting to find the error

Answer (score 0):

please clear your `generation` folder and check.
Another process is to run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` command

Comment: I run the command as well but nothing happen error show on screen 
RewardspointsFactory does not exist

Comment: Looking at the path that you have called in your __construct, i doubt that file exists, Test folder is generally reserved for the testing framework.

Comment: /home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/ResourceModel/Fee/Collection.php so the path i set is \Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Fee\CollectionFactory $rewardspointCollectionFactory

Comment: Do you have the test folder inside the model folder?

Comment: fix the path issue
but the cart page show me this any idea ?
Estimate Shipping and Tax

Comment: I did not get your point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83896/discussion-between-jhon-jhon-doe-and-sourabh-kumar-sharma).

Comment: page  blank and show 
Estimate Shipping and Tax

Comment: Did you check your log files in the var folder, f12 console error and view-source of page to get the idea what the error is ?

Comment: system.log file show me these errors

2018-10-01 11:33:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-10-01 11:33:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-10-01 11:33:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []

Comment: no error found in console
http://testing2.dukaania.com/checkout/cart/

Comment: I see error in your checkout page:  Cannot declare class Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Collection, because the name is already in use in <b>/home/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/ResourceModel/Fee/Collection.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br /> . Please fix it.

Comment: from where you can find this errors, the step you took to find out this error.
Please let me know, also please tell me where i call my class???

Comment: I saw your cart view source page and at the end of the page there was that error message.

Comment: also please let me know where i can put my class?

Comment: Please check your namespace declaration in this file: Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Collection.php. Check all the classes namespaces in your Test module, somewhere you have used two times same namespace.

Comment: changed namespace from
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Fee;

namespace Sugarcode\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Fee\Collection;
but nothing gonna work

Comment: You have to debug your namespace declaration and class name declaration, it should go to exact path.

Comment: can you please elobrate how can i debug my namespace 
i am new in magento2 highly appreciated

Comment: Check if your namespace resolves to correct class path or not.

Comment: path issue resolved now it show this error
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Sugarcode\Test\Model\Fee does not extend \Magento\Framework\DataObject

Comment: clear your generation folder.

Comment: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento setup:di:compile

i run these commands to clear those folders
but nothing gonna work

Comment: Is your asked question problem solved ? If it is solved then i think it will be good if you ask another question with full code posted in that question.

Comment: my issue is not reolved :/

Comment: Yes that is what i am suggesting you either edit the above question or ask a new question related to your namespace error, with code posted in that question.